# Signinig off android apk with the copy of keystore

Tags: android, release-management

Could someone please clarify if I can use a copy (created at release #1) of keystore for signing off a new release (let say release #3) of Android apk, if previous release (#2) was signed using original keystore? Or should I make a backup copy of an original keystore each time when a new release is signed off?

Comment: copying a file will never create problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use it any time you want, and any copy you want.

The important thing is that once you upload an APK and release it updates ONLY can be signed with the same keystore. You can and in fact you should store your keystore files at multiple places so you don't lose them. We did once and that was awful, would not recommend. :)

Comment: If you say "the same" you mean by that original keystore?

Comment: Yes, but it doesnt have to be physically the same file. You can copy a keystore, its just like any other file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same Keystore each time you want to create a Signed application using the same Password which you use to create Keystore.

If you use different details for new Keystore you will not be able to update the new build on Google Play. To update new version of same application apk must be signed with same Keystore each time.

You can also create new Keystore each time while signing the application but it is not needed as you can use the same copy of certificate.

Comment: It sounds that your opinion is different than @breakline

Comment: No, he misunderstood the question.  He's saying the keystore has to be identical to the original, which is true.  You can make 1000 copies of the file and they will all be interchangeable.

Comment: Exactly, Keystore must contain the identical information. You can create multiple copies with same information or by coping the same file. Only that is required is it's SHA1 and Hash Codes must be identical for each copy.